# One Group Policy not being applied

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

We have several group policies that are set up, but for some reason one of them is not being applied. It has in the past, and the Security Filtering is the same as on all the other GPOs.

The OU/AD structure has not changed either, so I'm a little lost for ideas as to what could be causing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As a first step, check that Resultant Set of Policy (RSoP) is showing the setting as being applied. If it doesn't then RSoP should give you the tools to track down the reason.

Assuming RSoP shows that the setting should apply but it still isn't you could enable verbose Group Policy debugging and sift thru the event log. Create a REG_DWOORD value "RunDiagnosticLoggingGlobal" at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Diagnostics" and setting it to "1" on one of the affected computers.

Problems with Group Policy application have, in my experience, almost always come down to unintended security filtering (or other scoping-related issue) or another GPO with a "conflicting" setting taking "precedence".

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I ran RSoP as a matter of course, as well as GPresult, and it isn't a case of the policies in the GPO being skipped, the whole policy is just not applied. It probably is something really silly with filtering (or conflict with another policy), but I'm at a loss as to what to check - the policy was applying fine on all servers yesterday.

Comment: David: When you say that the policy is not being applied, what exactly are you seeing in GPResults? Is it listed under Denied GPOs? If so, what reason is listed? What does Component Status show?

Comment: It was a case of GPresults just not reporting the GOP at all - not listed under denided, it was as if it was not being found. Randomly though, I've come to work this morning, and it's working again now. I'm very confused as to why, so will investigate further. Thanks for you time.