# Logon script does not run for all users

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy, javascript, logon-scripts

We have a standalone common-use workstation running **Windows XP Pro SP3** and have created a script using **Javascript** (`scriptname.js`) that is to be run for each user. The file was added as a user logon script via `gpedit.msc` and tested using a newly created user account as well as an existing user account. The script ran and functioned as intended on both accounts; however, a few existing users have informed us that the script is not running on their accounts.

All user accounts are members of the same groups and have identical permissions. We already have an existing script (but in this case, a **batch file**) that is applied in the same manner and it runs for all accounts without any problems. Furthermore, on the accounts where the new script does not run during logon, it can still be run manually and works fine.

So the question is: **what would cause this script to not run during logon on certain accounts?**

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [One Group Policy not being applied](http://serverfault.com/questions/393672/one-group-policy-not-being-applied)

Comment: It's likely a GPO scoping issue. My answer in the question referenced above is what I'd say here.

Comment: Does that even apply for a standalone (isolated) workstation? That sounds more like an issue related to a system that is actually connected to a domain where multiple GPOs are being applied.